# EPPlus Freeze panes is disabling vertical scrolling

Tags: c#, epplus

I wanted to freeze part the 6 first columns of my excel file while being able to scroll over the rest of the column and it only half-worked.
The freeze is perfectly working just as the horizontal scrolling, but when it comes to vertical scrolling, it doesn't not work at all.

I'm currently on EPPlus v6.0.5 (if that can matter)

Here is a screen of my excel file without freeze pane :
[excel file without freeze pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4lU8.png)

You can't see it on it, but it got 75 columns for 70 rows

Here are screens with freeze pane :
[with freeze pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lr3WW.png)
[with freeze pane, zoom out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmkKb.png)

As you can notice, I was able to move the unfreeze part (it gone to "lun 28 nov" at "jeu 1 déc"
But I lost the vertical scrolling, which means I can't see rows 42 to 70 and I don't understand why.

I also notice that the vertical scrollbar is significantly bigger without freeze pane, like with it, some virtual rows were created.

I tried many things, but it didn't worked, and I'm currently runing with Split Pane which is working pretty well but got the default to copy the first six rows on the second Pane.

Here is the code line I'm using :

`excelWorksheet.View.FreezePanes(compteurligne,6 );`
with "compteurligne" being a variable (the number of rows in my excel)

If someone can help me to understand what I'm doing wrong, thanks in advance !

Comment: The vertical scrollbar looks fine. Post *code* that reproduces the problem instead of images, something people can run and check in Excel. Post code that generates eg 100 rows, then freezes the first 6.

Comment: `with "compteurligne" being a variable (the number of rows in my excel)` do you mean 70? Then you explicitly froze all the data. In Excel itself, `Freeze Panes` freezes all rows above the current cell. The equivalent VBA macro expects the coordinates of the first *non*-frozen cell, and so does EPPlus. If you want to freeze the first 15 rows, use `FreezePanges(16,6)`